# Setting axis limits with log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a graph and I'm almost happy with it. I just want to change the limit of the x-axis (log-scale). I tried to set limits in scale_x_continuous, but that results in one straight vertical line, instead of ten S-curves. My code untill now is:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(evaporation, aes(x = evaporation$h)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C1_theta, color = "blue"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C2_theta, color = "blue"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C3_theta, color = "blue"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C4_theta, color = "blue"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = C5_theta, color = "blue"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S1_theta, color = "green"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S2_theta, color = "green"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S3_theta, color = "green"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S4_theta, color = "green"), size = 1.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = S5_theta, color = "green"), size = 1.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log", breaks = c(0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000), limits = 0, 100000) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = expression(theta ~ (cm^3/cm^3)), x = "Absolute Pressure Head h (cm)") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Samples",
                     labels = c("Control sample", "Treated sample"),
                     values = c("#4472C4", "#70AD47")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.82, 0.72), legend.direction = "vertical", legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black", linetype = "solid"))
```

Does anyone know how to make sure the x-axis stops at 100000?

Comment: If your x-axis is log-scale then `log(0)` evaluates to -Inf. Have you tried setting the limits as `c(NA, 100000)`? Also you should assign a two length vector to the limits (not `limits = 0, 100000`).

Answer (score 0):

So there are two options, the first one as @teunbrand indicates is to set the limits as c(NA, 1000000). It will look like:

```r
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log", breaks = c(0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000), limits = c(NA, 100000))
```

Check the parenthesis and the "c".

The second option is to erase the limits from scale_x_continuous, and instead use

```r
xlim()
```

It will look like:

```r
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log", breaks = c(0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)) +
xlim(0, 100000)
```

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for the editing! Aswering from a mobile is a real challenge when it comes to code